# Set autocommit using dplyr connector

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr

Is there a way to `SET AUTOCOMMIT TO ON` using dplyr's `src_postgres` connector? I've read the instructions on setting up new DB connections described in the [docs](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/new-sql-backend.html), but didn't see a way to pass arbitrary SQL configuration commands to the underlying `dbconnect` function.

Comment: You can use regular DBI commands on the con component of the src: `DBI::dbSendQuery(src$con, "SET AUTOCOMMIT TO ON")`

Comment: @hadley's suggestion works well. If you want to submit it as an answer, I'd gladly accept it.